# what pattern should I include so that my code recognizes brackets?

Tags: r, gsub, dplyr

I have a dataframe in which it has columns titled in this order "m.z, Intensity, Relative, Delta., RBD.equiv. and Composition" and in each row it has these parameters filled according to a specific molecule. In the composition column it has something such as " C7 H11 O4" I have a code in which I am able to separate the elements "C, H, O,... and so on" into column titles and below it will be the number of elements according to the molecular formula. However when a Carbon isotope is shown in the composition, "C11 [13]C H21 O N3 S2" the code fails and gives me an error. I want to be able to have [13]C as its own column so that I can distinguish this from other molecules.

my data.frame looks like this below but with hundreds of more compositions. Dataframe comes from a csv file for reference. I'm not sure what pattern to use in gsub so that the [13]C is turned into a column with its respective rows.

```
#This is how my data frame looks like but with more rows

#m.z  Intensity  Relative  Delta.  RBD.equiv  Composition 
#275  7555870    100       -0.49   0.0        C3 [13]C H4 O2
#136  126098     70.67     -2.72   5.5        C7 H11 O4 Na S

    data <- dataframe%>%mutate(Composition=gsub("\\b([A-Za-z]+)\\b","\\11",Composition),

    name=str_extract_all(Composition,"[A-Za-z]+"),

    value=str_extract_all(Composition,"\\d+"))%>%
    unnest()%>%spread(name,value,fill=0)

#I expect to see something like this when I print my results

#m.z Intensity Relative Delta. RBD.equiv Composition   C [13]C H O Na
#275 7555870   100      -0.49  0.0       C3 [13]C H4   3 1     4 0 0
#133 126098    70.67    -2.72  5.5       C7 H5 O4 Na   7 0     5 4 1
```

Comment: This may be a tough problem, assuming the molecule could contain any elements.  Is there a fixed number of expected elements?

Comment: So I try to keep it between a certain amount usually, such as C, H, O, N, Na, S, Si, but sometimes I do add in extra elements.

Answer (score 0):

edit: I managed to fix regular exxpressions in your code:

```
data <- dataframe %>% mutate(Composition = gsub("\\b([A-Za-z]+)\\b", "\\11", Composition),
                           name=str_extract_all(Composition, "(\\[[0-9]+\\])*[A-Za-z]+"), #allow numer in square bracket before element
                           value=str_extract_all(Composition, "(?<!\\[[0-9]{0,5})[0-9]+")) %>% #only numbers that are not in square brackets (I expect the number in square bracket has 5 digits max)
    unnest() %>% spread(name, value, fill = 0)
```

my first solution was to separate elements from molecular formula first and then apply regex for every element:

(note that I'm using splitstackshape package in my solution for separation as I'm used to it. You can change it if you're familiar to any other solution)

```
data <-  dataframe %>% mutate(CompositionCopy = gsub("\\b([A-Za-z]+)\\b", "\\11", Composition)) %>% #your code
    splitstackshape::cSplit("CompositionCopy", " ", fixed = TRUE, direction = "long", type.convert = FALSE) %>% #split
    mutate(name = str_extract_all(CompositionCopy, ".*[A-Za-z]+"), #included .* into your regex
           value = str_extract_all(CompositionCopy, "\\d+$") %>% as.integer()) %>% #included $ in your regex to only get number at the end
    select(-CompositionCopy) %>% 
    spread(name, value, fill = 0L)
```